# How to combine Node.js ,MongoDb and Backbone.js in one application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express

I want to design a simple accounting web application using  NodeJS + MongoDB to build the backend API and use Backbone JS to build the front-end app.

I know these languages separately but facing problem in combining them. I goggled a lot but did not get a satisfactory answer. This is just for my own learning.

It should:

- allow us to  create users(Name,Email,Pid)
- List all users
- create projects for the users

I have done this using php+mysql+bootstrap earlier.

I want to do it using node,mongo and backbone .

How can I get started.please provide some details.

Comment: Have a look at some node / mongodb / backbone tutorials and examples - google is your friend

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I know these languages . I am facing problem in integratetion. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

[MEANJS](http://meanjs.org/)
|
[Backbone boilerplate](https://github.com/backbone-boilerplate/backbone-boilerplate)
|
[BENM](https://github.com/shorttompkins/benm)

jfgi